# Route missing on nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Not sure why this isn't working. It was working perfectly and then I restarted the server. I am getting a no route error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"issues"}
```

Here is the helper i am trying to call:

```
<%= link_to "Add Issue", new_app_issue_path %>
```

and my routes file:

```
  resources :apps do
    resources :issues
  end
```

Why would it break all of a sudden? And I obviously have the route:

```
    app_issues GET    /apps/:app_id/issues(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"issues"}
               POST   /apps/:app_id/issues(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"issues"}
 new_app_issue GET    /apps/:app_id/issues/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"issues"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify *what* app this is for:

```
new_app_issue_path(an_app_object_or_an_app_objects_id)
```

Rails would only "guess" this if `params[:app_id]` was available, which doesn't appear to be the case here.